# How to play a sound after a dispatch without user interaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to play a song when an action is being dispatched. There is no user interaction and the action is being triggered by an external API, so the user never needs to do anything, the display of the screen changes automatically.

This is my code :

```
    newAppointmentsCalled.forEach((appointment) => {
      const appointmentIsNotYetCalled =
        appointmentsCalled.findIndex((a) => a.id === appointment.id) === -1
      if (appointmentIsNotYetCalled) {
        dispatch({
          type: 'PATIENT_CALLED',
          payload: appointment,
        })
        sound.play()
      }
    })
```

I'm inside a useEffect, I tried to add a setTimeout but this doesn't change anything, I still get the error :

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Browsers prevent audio from playing without user interaction: this is intentional and by design (to prevent annoying/abusive code behavior among other reasons).

Comment: So there is no way to do it ?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75072581/how-to-play-a-sound-after-a-dispatch-without-user-interaction?noredirect=1#comment132480147_75072581) Sure: play the audio in response to a user interaction.

Comment: Is there a way to turn my dispatch as a user interaction ?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75072581/how-to-play-a-sound-after-a-dispatch-without-user-interaction?noredirect=1#comment132480454_75072581) There's no way we could answer that because you haven't provided a [mre]. See [ask].

Comment: There's nothing more to understand, I simply dispatch an action, the description I've provided is purely enough to understand the scope of my question. There's no user interaction at all, a simple API call does the job and depending on the answers I get, I update the display

Comment: An idea: depending on how you designed it, requiring the user to press a button or something will meet the requirement of user interaction.